# How to properly submit a form with jquery ajax method (post) with codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I've build a small CMS in Codeigniter for a website with a couple of forms.
The forms are all submitted with the ajax method in jQuery and passed to the controller. All works fine but I figured it out that I always get a success, no matter if the data is saved in the database or not. The method only checks if the data is passed to the controller properly, i guess. On success there is a message for the user (Saved), this will fire everytime, no matter what happens behind the scenes. How I can force success (or done, or some other callback) to get the "Saved" message only if the data is saved?

Here is the code:

```
//javascript
$("#save_club").click(function(){

    var club_name = $('input[name="club_name"]').val();
    var location = $('input[name="location"]').val();
    var phone = $('input[name="phone"]').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: base_url + "/clubs/save_club/",
        data: {club_name:club_name,location:location,phone1:phone1},
        success:function(data)
        {
            $('input[type="submit"]').attr("value", "Saved!");
            $('input[type="submit"]').css("background-color", "#32c310");
            $('input[type="submit"]').css("cursor", "default");
            $(".dynamic_content").load(base_url + "/clubs/clubs_list");
        }
    });     
});

//controller
public function save_club(){
    $newdata = array();
    $newdata['club_name'] = $this->input->post("club_name");
    $newdata['location'] = $this->input->post("location");
    $newdata['phone'] = $this->input->post("phone");
    $this->load->model("model_save");
    $this->model_save->save_club_to_db($newdata);
}
```

Comment: The `success` function will run if the request to the server does not return an error. You could change the HTTP status of the response to an error code like 500, and `success` would not run, instead `error` would if you passed in a function for it.

Answer (score 0):

You first would need to validate the inputs with PHP. For example:

```
<?php
$success = 'true';
foreach($_POST as $input) {
  if ($input == '') {
    $success = 'false';
    break;
  }
}
echo $success;
?>
```

Next, check the return with the `data` var you passed in the success function:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: base_url + "/clubs/save_club/",
    data: {club_name:club_name,location:location,phone1:phone1},
    success:function(data)
    //Whatever PHP echoes in the script gets put into the variable data
    {
        var result = (data ? 'saved!' : 'error!'); //data should either be true or false
        $('input[type="submit"]').attr("value", result);
        $('input[type="submit"]').css("background-color", "#32c310");
        $('input[type="submit"]').css("cursor", "default");
        $(".dynamic_content").load(base_url + "/clubs/clubs_list");
    }
});
```

Comment: @Palmer You can't echo an boolean. Use strings.

Comment: codeigniter has a validation class that is far more robust than what you are suggesting. `data` in response is a string, not a boolean so `var result` will always be `'saved'` regardless of what gets sent back

Comment: charlieftl, i know codeigniter has it own class for validation. If I combine mine code with this class, maybe I'll get what I need. I'll give a try!